# After registration, my login page is not verifying username name and password

Tags: php, mysql

I have been writing the code for a login page, and it does not work as I expected.

Whenever I want to log user in, I enter the correct username and password. But for some reason, it always shows invalid username or password.

It should receive the correct information and log me in, but it doesn’t and I don’t understand why.

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();
 
// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
 
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Password is not valid, display a generic error message
                            $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Username doesn't exist, display a generic error message
                    $login_err = "Invalid username or password.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

What is causing this weird behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should also show the way you inserted those hashed password, the php side has a tgood exampe that works.

Comment: Please add a `var_dump($password, $hashed_password);` before the `password_verify()` call for debugging purposes. What is the output you get? When you don't get any output, add additional `var_dump()` or `echo` lines before the `if()` statements you have to check why the `if()` block isn't executed.